# REST Client with content type JSON

Tags: json, rest

I am calling REST service with JSON request using Apache HTTPClient and it gives me 415 unsupported media type error.

It works fine with some API but failed with the error:

```java
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Create new getRequest with below mentioned URL
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("example URL");

String encoding = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary("usrname:pwd".getBytes("UTF-8"));
getRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

StringEntity params = new StringEntity("");

params.setContentType("application/json");

// Execute your request and catch response
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

// Check for HTTP response code: 200 = success
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + 
        response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}

// Get-Capture Complete application body response
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((
    response.getEntity().getContent())));
String output;
System.out.println("============Output:============");

// Simply iterate through response and show on console.
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: when are you assigning the `params` to `getRequest`? You just created that property but didn't assign it to the original request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need the `StringEntity` in your `GET` request. Just try the following:

```java
getRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE "application/json");
```